# Sequence of bump functions with an additional integral condition on the gradient

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

My question is simple: Is there a sequence of functions $f_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that

- $0\le f_n\le 1$ for all $n$
- $f_n\to 1$ pointwise
- $\int|\nabla f_n|^2\,dx\le 1/n$ for all $n$?

I know that the first two points are doable by choosing bump functions $f_n$ such that $f_n = 1$ on $B_n(0)$ and $f_n=0$ outside of $B_{n+1}(0)$.

For dimension $d=1$ I'd choose $g_n=1$ on $[-n,n]$, $g_n = 0$ on $(-\infty,-2n]\cup [2n,\infty)$ and fill up linearly in the two gaps. This function satisfies all three points, but isn't smooth. However, I'm sure $g_n$ can be approximated uniformly by a smooth function $f_n$ so that $(f_n)$ does the job. But I have no idea how to deal with higher-dimensional cases.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be $\le 1/n$? Can it be $\le 2/n$ or $\le C/n$ for a positive $C$? In the latter case I reckon it will be much easier. (Hope it is clear what I mean)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, of course. I think, actually, it suffices for my purposes that the integrals tend to zero.

Comment: For $d=1$, your argument should work. For $d>2$, I think that the Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality (see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) combined with Fatou's lemma shows that this is impossible. I am not sure about the case $d=2$ right now. Not sure how the sobolev embeddings look like in that case.

Comment: Ok, for $d=2$ you get an estimate of the BMO norm of $f$ by the $L^2$ norm of the gradient of $f$ (see again the Wikipedia article). Now the question is if some form of Fatou's lemma holds for BMO.

Comment: Hm, the problem is that the constant functions actually have BMO norm zero. So: no idea about the case $d=2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks a lot!!! That Gagliardo–Nirenberg–Sobolev inequality (which I wasn't aware of) indeed prohibits the existence of such a sequence for $d\ge 3$, and, in fact, I doubt that this is possible for $d=2$. Please make your comment an answer so I can acknowledge it and close this case.